# Bitmap is recycled...?

Tags: android

I was making a game's UI system. But I noticed a strange problem: Bitmap seems to be recycled

I haven't recycled any bitmap yet(which is I will do later).
But what logcat says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 1050
Process: gippeumi.youckma, PID: 19044
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: bitmap is recycled
  at android.opengl.GLUtils.texImage2D(GLUtils.java:160)
  at gippeumi.youckma.graphics.util.GLTextureManager.Set(GLTextureManager.java:53)
  at gippeumi.youckma.graphics.ui.element.UIElement.UpdateTexture(UIElement.java:64)
  at gippeumi.youckma.graphics.ui.element.TextLabel.OnRender(TextLabel.java:42)
  at gippeumi.youckma.graphics.ui.element.UIElement.Render(UIElement.java:71)
  at gippeumi.youckma.graphics.ui.Screen.Render(Screen.java:50)
  at gippeumi.youckma.graphics.GameRenderer.onDrawFrame(GameRenderer.java:52)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1531)
  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1248)
```

I never thought that bitmap can be recycled by system. Maybe I did something wrong while creating bitmap.

```
public abstract class UIElement {
    private static final String TAG = "UI Element";
    private static final int WH_SCALER = 100;

    private String name;
    private CoreRect rect;
    private int tex;
    private float x, y;
    private float w, h;
    private Bitmap bmp;

    protected UIElement(String Name, float X, float Y, float Width, float Height) {
        name = Name;
        x = X;
        y = Y;
        w = Width;
        h = Height;
        rect = new CoreRect(Width, Height, false);
        bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap((int)(Width * WH_SCALER), (int)(Height * WH_SCALER), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        onCreate(bmp);
    }

    public float GetX() {
        return x;
    }

    public float GetY() {
        return y;
    }

    public float GetWidth() {
        return w;
    }

    public float GetHeight() {
        return h;
    }

    public String GetName() {
        return name;
    }

    protected abstract void OnCreate(Bitmap Bmp);
    private void onCreate(Bitmap Bmp) {
        GLTextureManager.Lock();
        OnCreate(Bmp);
        tex = GLTextureManager.Add(Bmp);
        GLTextureManager.Unlock();
    }

    protected void UpdateTexture() {
        Log.d(TAG, "Texture updated");
        GLTextureManager.Set(tex, bmp);
    }

    protected abstract void OnRender(Bitmap Bmp);
    public void Render() {
        //Log.d(TAG, "Render()");
        GLTextureManager.Lock();
        OnRender(bmp);
        rect.Render(x, y, GLTextureManager.Get(tex));
        GLTextureManager.Unlock();
    }
}
```

NOTE: This is what GLTextureManager.Set does(I will edit GL10 to GLES20 later.):

```
//Bind specified texture
GLES20.glBindTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, glTextures[Index]);

//Setup
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
GLES20.glTexParameterf(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

//Use Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, Bmp, 0);
```

Comment: were you able to resolve this? I'm encountering a similar issue.